# Should I pass async function to passport.deserializeUser()?

Tags: serialization, async-await, passport.js, session-cookies

I am using `passport` to handle user authentication. During initialization, I have to do the following for managing the session cookies:

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.ID));
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => done(null, getUserById(id)));
```

Here, I have stored the users in my database, so `getUserById` is an asynchronous function, defined as follows:

```js
const getUserById = async (id) => {
    result = await executeQuery(`SELECT ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM STUDENTS WHERE ID=:id`, [id]);
    if (result.rows.length != 0) return result.rows[0];
    else return null;
};
```

Here, `getUserById(id)` function does not immediately return the result from query execution, it returns a `promise`. What is the proper way to pass this `getUserById()` function to `done()`?

- Should I wrap `getUserById(id)` in another IIFE async function?
- Or should I do the following?

```js
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const user = await getUserById(id);
    done(null, user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to mind:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    getUserById(id).then(user => done(null, user))
};
```

I.e., handle the promise using `then()`. I don't know if `deserializeUser` will take an asynchronous call-back function. I do know some functions like `useEffect` in React don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass async function and use await in try-catch block. You can do something like this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await getUserById(id);
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    return done(error);
  }
});
```